# What A Crazy Night

Tags: logical-deduction, language

Having decided to accept an invitation to a party, you arrive at midnight in full dress. However, inside the mansion is a scene of madness.

> across the Hall, a Star flings a Cup of Water at an American with Silver Hair. you pick up a Cake and Straw from the Truck and notice an Eagle playing with a Ball. a Gun goes off and Bullets spray from the Weapon. as you run, a Man from Town pulls you behind the Garbage. "Smith," he says.

Yet amidst the chaos, you see mostly orderly pairs and only one outlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the outlier is a

> STAR

because the pairs are

> GARBAGE TRUCK, WEAPONSMITH, STRAW MAN, CUPCAKE, TOWN HALL, WATER GUN, AMERICAN EAGLE, HAIRBALL, SILVER BULLETS.

Comment: You beat me by about twenty seconds or so. Don't you just hate it when that happens?

Comment: No, I love it when that happens. The other way around is a pain, though. :-) (Actually, I don't particularly love it. Sorry to have scooped you by so short an amount.)

Comment: Incidentally, I'm reasonably confident that there aren't other ways to pair 'em up that yield a different odd one out, though I haven't tried to draw the entire graph and check.

Comment: correct! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Taking a clue from "you see mostly orderly pairs and only one outlier", you can pair up almost all the capitalised words in the story to form words or expressions:
>
>  Garbage Truck
>  Straw Man
>  Hair Ball
>  Cup Cake
>  Town Hall
>  Water Gun
>  American Eagle
>  Silver Bullets
>  Weapon Smith
>
>  That leaves only **Star** as an unmatched word.

I'm not sure this is correct because there are a few alternative

> pairings such as Silver Smith.

Comment: Correct as well! However, it seems like Gareth McCaughan was a little faster :(